# Add more space to top of the UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am creating a UITableView and i need to add some more space to top of the table. I used ContentInset to do that, but it doesn't seem to work for me.

```
_tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,60, 320, 361) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
        _tableView.delegate = self;
        _tableView.dataSource = self;
        _tableView.rowHeight = 119;
        _tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [_tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
```

This is my Table.

```
[_tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(44.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)];
```

I added this code to shift my content down little bit, but it doesn't work for me. What i need is table should display content with having little bit space at the top. But when i scroll the table up, table should scroll the content all way to the top. I dont want to add extra cell to the top of the table and disable user interaction for that row and use that as extra space. Also its going to be huge unwanted coding inside my project. There should be easy way to add this little extra space to the top of the table.

If some one give me any solution for this or any idea how to do this, That would be very greatful

Here is a image of what i need to do.

[image]

Comment: What about a simple headerView, would that be satisfactory?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. But the problem is can't use that method bcs i m using pull to reload function like twitter to my table. I need this gap between rows and pull to reload thing :) .. any way thanks for the reply

Comment: Alright. Could you make a sketch which shows "exactly" what you want to achieve. That would help us help you out better.

Comment: i added the image to my question. I think you can have some idea by looking at it.

Comment: In short, you want to add that blueish bar on top of your tableview. And make the table scroll through it? Also it needs to react on touches so it reload your view or whatever else you want to do with it when you pull it down?

Comment: basically yeah. But table content should be in the same position. You can see there is little gap between the blue bar and the table. So that should stay as it is, and also the table should scroll through the blue bar.

Comment: Alright, you want to have apart from the blueish bar, a transparant inbetweenView the blueish bar and the tableview. This view will make it appear to the user as if it will move through the bar but instead just cover it slightly with a slight (0,5 alpha? maybe some sort of color) transparancy. This will also appear as a bit of a gap but not   not in a disturbing way. If and only if you want if to disappear as you scroll or stop scrolling or whatever then you should just hide this inbetweenView.

Comment: Can U explain this solution little bit .... I still didn't get you...

Comment: How about making the height of the first cell a little taller and then aligning the content in that cell to the bottom using heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath.  Then place the tableview a bit higher up so it goes underneath the blue bar.